# Trouble after converting standalone Plone instance to ZEO -- only one client starts

Tags: plone, zope

I'm trying to convert a standalone Plone instance to a ZEO cluster.  I have the ZEO server and three clients on the same machine.  I modified the buildout, cleared the buildout cache, and reran bin/buildout.  Everything seemed to work.  In fact, when I run bin/startcluster.sh everything looks like it's working, except then if I use bin/clusterstatus.sh I'll see that only client1 is running.

If I try running bin/zeo fg I get the following:

```
root@dev:/opt/Plone/zinstance# bin/zeo fg
/opt/Plone/zinstance/parts/zeo/bin/runzeo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 397, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 394, in main
s.main()
  File "/opt/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ZEO/runzeo.py", line 165, in main
self.server.close()
AttributeError: StorageServer instance has no attribute 'close'
```

The zeo.log file shows the process repeatedly exiting with status 1 and restarting but doesn't give me anything more detailed.

First of all, what is the problem I'm having?  Secondly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Well I gave in and reinstalled it (i.e., ./install.sh zeo) and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the install.sh script again to fix.